# Converting char array to int

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, arduino-leonardo, nrf24l01+, wireless

I'm trying to use nRF24L01 module to send a messages between 2 arduinos

Transmiter code:

```
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));

  delay(1000);
```

Reciver code:

```
char text[32] = {0};
radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));

Serial.println(text);
```

How I can put into char array an int value?
I tried doing it in this way

For example:
      int a = 60;
      const char text[] = String(a);
      radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));

```
  delay(1000);
```

Comment: `radio.println(a)` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for a way to get an arbitrary number expressed as a string? If so, you'll likely want to use some existing functions to help you along.

I recommend using [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

```
sprintf(char * str, char * format, args)
```

Where str is the string you're storing results in, format is the string you're inserting your values into for, you guessed it, formatting, and args are all the args, separated by commas, that you'll be passing into the format string to be inserted into the str string. An example might be:

```
char[x] result;    //x is the number of elements in your array, atleast one for every letter and one for the end character, ex: "hello" needs 6.
int number = 24;
sprintf(result, "My number is %d", number);
sendSomewhere(result);   //sends "My number is 24"
```

Comment: You forgot to declare the size of `result`. Also, if your “somewhere” inherits from `Print` (most things that implement `write()` do), then you can `somewhere.print("My number is "); somewhere.print(24);`.

Comment: I did forget to declare a size for result! for OP, that line should read "char[x] result" where x is the number of elements in your char array. 
As for sendSomewhere(result), it was just supposed to be an open-ended function for the OP to get the concept with.

Comment: 1) By `char[x] result;` you probably mean `char result[x];`. 2) I understand the virtues of an open-ended answer, but using `sprintf()` instead of `Print::print()` will make the compiled program grow by 1 K or so. If the program already uses `Print::print()` (which is likely, since it is so common in Arduinoland), then the cost of `sprintf()` is more like 1.5 K.

Comment: `sprtintf()` returns the length of the string created so you can do `int length=sprintf(result, "My number is %d", number); radio.write(result, length);` This saves using `strlen()` to calculate how many bytes to send.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have 'const' prefixed the 'text' variable as it then become 'read-only'.

```
    char text[32];
    int a = 60;
    sprintf(text, "Number %d", a);
    radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to send the integer in binary format (skipping the conversion to text).

```
int a = 60; 
radio.write((char*) &a, sizeof(a));
```

Cheers!